# Geting a Typeerror with hashes (No implicit conversion of symbol into integer)

Tags: ruby, hash

I made a sample script. Here is the sample script I am running:

```
def array_generator
  signalp_array = Array.new(11){ Array.new(11,0) }
  signalp = Hash.new
  file = File.readlines("./sample.txt")
  file.each_with_index do |line, idx|
    row = line.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').chomp.split(" ") # split the line into a array based on white space.
    signalp_array[idx][0..row.length - 1] = row # Merge into existing array
  end
  signalp_array.each do |g|
    seq_id = g[0] 
    cut_off = g[4]
    d_value = g[8]
    signalp[seq_id] = [:cut_off => cut_off, :d_value => d_value] 
  end
  return signalp
 end

signalp = array_generator

puts signalp 
signalp.each do |id, neww|
  puts id
  puts neww[ :cut_off]
  puts neww[ :d_value]
end
```

with which I am getting the following output and error:

```
isotig00001_f1_3
in `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

Since the `puts signalp` line gives me the following:

```
{"isotig00001_f1_3"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.132"}], "isotig00001_f1_5"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.162"}], "isotig00001_f1_7"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.397"}], "isotig00001_f1_8"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.259"}], "isotig00001_f1_9"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.110"}], "isotig00001_f1_10"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.135"}], "isotig00001_f1_11"=>[{:cut_off=>"1", :d_value=>"0.000"}], "isotig00001_f1_12"=>[{:cut_off=>"12", :d_value=>"0.117"}], "isotig00001_f2_0"=>[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.108"}], "isotig00001_f2_1"=>[{:cut_off=>"28", :d_value=>"0.122"}], "isotig00001_f2_3"=>[{:cut_off=>"19", :d_value=>"0.097"}]}
```

the hash is created properly. However I cannot access the `:cut_off` and `:d_value` individually (probably, because they are digits). I tried `to_i`, `to_s` methods etc.

1. Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong?
2. Any ideas on what to search for or where to learn more on the topic?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`neww` is not a hash, it is an array `[{:cut_off=>"11", :d_value=>"0.132"}]`. Do

```
puts neww[0][:cut_off]
puts neww[0][:d_value]
```

Answer (score 3):

The values in your `neww` hash are *arrays* of hashes, not just bare hashes. You need to index into the array before keying into the hash. That is:

```
puts neww[0][:cut_off]
```